# I'm trying to create an APEX Batch Class on custom object, but getting an error

Tags: apex, batch, class

Getting an error when trying to create this batch class. Could you advise what I'm doing wrong?

> Error: Compile Error: Class LocationProcessorBatch must implement the method: void Database.Batchable.execute(Database.BatchableContext, List) at line 1 column 14

```
global class LocationProcessorBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

global Integer count = 0;

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
    return Database.getQueryLocator('Select Id, Next_Inspection_Date__c FROM SVMXC_Site__c');
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<SVMXC_Site__c> l_list){        
    List<SVMXC_Site__c> l_list_new = new List<SVMXC_Site__c>();
    for(SVMXC_Site__c l:l_list){
        l.Next_Inspection_Date= Month()+'/15/'+Year();
        l_list_new.add(l);
        count+=1;
    }
    update l_list_new;
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
    System.debug('Count='+count);
   }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] to include the complete error text, stack trace (if any), and line location.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is on this line:

```
l.Next_Inspection_Date= Month()+'/15/'+Year();
```

You have missing `__c` in the field name.

It should be written as one or other as below.

1. Assuming you are using `month()` and `year()` methods from `Date` class on a date variable:

   ```
   Date myDate = date.newInstance(2019, 10, 29);
   l.Next_Inspection_Date__c = myDate.month() + '/15/' + myDate.year();
   ```

   OR
2. Assuming you already have a `Month()`, and `Year()` methods defined in your class.

   ```
   l.Next_Inspection_Date__c = Month() + '/15/' + Year();
   ```

Comment: Will myDate.month() get me the current month and myDate.year() get me the current year?

Comment: It will give you with what you initialized `myDate`, in the above example it will be 10 and 2019. Depends on what you are trying to achieve. Refer to [`Date` class' documentation for more details](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm)

Comment: Ok, I believe this is what I need:             

l.Next_Inspection_Date__c= System.Today().Month() +'/15/'+ System.Today().Year();

Comment: I'm still getting the original error: Error: Compile Error: Class LocationProcessorBatch must implement the method: void Database.Batchable.execute(Database.BatchableContext, List) at line 1 column 14

Comment: If I change the first line to global class LocationProcessorBatch implements Database.Batchable<SVMXC_Site__c> then get the error message Error: Compile Error: Invalid type: SVMXC_Site__c at line 1 column 48

Comment: I literally copy pasted your code and changed the object and query and the issue is as mentioned the way you are trying to use the custom field. You may need to review the missing parts here otherwise from batch implementation perspective, you have the right interface and methods in here.

Comment: I found the issue. I misspelled the custom object name (missing an underscore). It was all correct and working.

Comment: Also, I changed the date line to this and it worked perfectly:             l.Next_Inspection_Date__c= date.parse(System.Today().Month() +'/15/'+ System.Today().Year());